# Loop gives other results

Tags: python, delphi

I have this python code here:

```
spalte=5
for x in range(spalte):
    print x 
    print spalte 
    for i in range(spalte-1):
        print i 
        print spalte-1
```

And the pascal / delphi loop here:

```
spalte=5
for x := 0 to spalte do
begin
  writeln(x);
  writeln(spalte);
  for i := 0 to (spalte-1) do
    writeln(i);
    writeln(spalte-1);
end;
```

I get the right values from the python loop but in the pascal loop the values are different.
Has this anything to do with the nested loops ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated]** based on @Amxx observation:

```
for x := 0 to spalte-1 do
begin
  writeln(x);
  writeln(spalte);
  for i := 0 to (spalte-1-1) do
    begin
      writeln(i);
      writeln(spalte-1);
    end;
end;
```

Your pascal code is equivalent with:

```
for x in range(spalte+1):
    print x 
    print spalte
    for i in range(spalte):
        print i 
    print spalte-1
```

Comment: So, he's missing the begin and end so only the first statement is in the loop?

Comment: @valentin this is weird , then something is wrong with my compiler http://prntscr.com/6y5xtk

Comment: @ytl96875 your python and pascal loops are not equivalent ... more in may answer

Comment: no, you should rather change the final value of your loop in one of the 2 langage ...

Answer (score 3):

You have to notice that

```
for i in range(spalte):
```

is NOT the python equivalent of

```
for i := 0 to spalte do
```

In fact the python `range(n)` run through every value from 0 to n-1 (excluding n) while the pascal loop goes from 0 to n (including n)

---

This is in addition for the missing `begin`/`end` in the most nested loop of your pascal program